# PHP error trying to write to MongoDB replica set

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm having trouble writing/upserting to a replicaset located on another machine.  Here's the code that is executed:

```
<?php
//Create a connection
$connection = new Mongo("mongodb://user:password@mycompany.com:27017/dbName", array("persist" => "pcName", "replicaSet"=>"myReplSet"));

//Select a database
$db = $connection->dbName;

//Select a collection
$collection = $db->testCollection;

//Add a record
$obj = array("FirstName" => "Brian", "LastName"=>"Renze", "Email"=>"abc@me.com");
$collection->insert($obj);
?>
```

And I'm receiving an error: *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'bad or malformed command request?'* followed by *Next exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'couldn't determine master'*

Nothing is being written to the database, but I'm not sure whats wrong with the code I'm using.  It's an almost exact copy out of the php-mongo tutorial on php.net.

Our mongoDB instances are only available when connecting directly to a database (dbName in this case), so should I take out the "Select a database" step?

How do I find the master instance for the replicaSet?  Shouldn't that happen automatically?

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Brian Renzenbrink

Comment: Is $collection = $db-> testCollection missing a semi-colon?

Comment: It was in the question I posted, but not in my code.  I've edited to fix that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use a replica set without having one setup.

If you remove the `replicaSet` paramater:

```
$connection = new Mongo("mongodb://user:password@mycompany.com:27017/dbName", array("persist" => "pcName"));
```

That should work.

If it doesn't work could you include the version of mongo, php, mongo-php, and the version of your operating system?

You can read more about replication here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication

You can read more about connecting here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.php

Comment: That removes the error, but I'm not successfully inserting data into the DB.  I don't see a new collection titled 'testCollection' being created when I connect to the master node.

Comment: Mongo version 1.85, php version 5.3.6, mongo-php version 1.2.4

Comment: There is no error, and when I echo the data I see that a MongoId has been created for the $obj.  Unfortunately, it's not being written to the DB.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right database to see the new collection?

You could run: `show dbs`, then `use` whatever database name you have... then `db.testCollection.find()`

Comment: I am definitely on the same db.  When executing `show collections` I don't the 'testCollection' db, which should have been created.

Comment: I think we may be going up the wrong tree here, because the db I am trying to write to is definitely a ReplicaSet.  Could there have been something else wrong with my original connection parameters?

Comment: So it looks like I wasn't using the correct replicaSet name in the connection parameters, which was our block.  Unfortunately, I've got a different issue appearing now.  I've edited the bottom of the original post to include this data.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: So what is the issue you're having now? Any errors or just the info not showing up?

Comment: I still get the *bad or malformed exception* first, but that is followed by *Next exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'couldn't determine master'*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13529/discussion-between-ranman-and-brian-renzenbrink)